# Getting an extra undefined value in printArray function using while loop

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, I am trying to write a simple function to print array elements using while statement, but I am getting an extra undefined value at the end. Any help will be highly appreciated

Codes are:

```
var a = [1, 3, 6, 78, 87];

function printArray(a) {

    if (a.length == 0) {
        document.write("the array is empty");
    } else {
        var i = 0;
        do {
            document.write("the " + i + "element of the array is " + a[i] + "</br>");

        }
        while (++i < a.length);
    }
}

document.write(printArray(a) + "</br>");
```

and the output is:

```
the 0element of the array is 1
the 1element of the array is 3
the 2element of the array is 6
the 3element of the array is 78
the 4element of the array is 87
undefined
```

How I am getting the undefined value? Am I skipping any index? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because your `printArray` function is not returning any value, which means it is actually returning `undefined`

You could fix this in two ways:

1. Change `document.write(printArray(a) + "</br>");` to `printArray(a);document.write("<br/>")`]
2. Make your printArray return a string instead of doing `document.write` and keep your other code

Second way is more recommended and also note that using `document.write` is not recommended either, try setting `document.body.innerHTML` or something like that

Would recommend reading these for future reference as well:

[Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Why is document.write a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [1, 3, 6, 78, 87];

function myFunction() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < a.length) {
        document.write("the " + i + "element of the array is " + a[i] + "</br>");
        i++;
    }
}
```